# Only import NSURLSession in OS X 10.8 , but don't use

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

i am writing a app with 10.8+ requiments.
Now i want to use NSURLSession for os x above 10.8 and use NSURLConnection for os x **10.8 only**

I have two http client. httpClientA with superClass of NSURLSessionManager and httpClientB with superClass NSURLConnection. when i check system version is above 10.8 , then i use httpClientB. that's what i want.

but , when my app start on 10.8 system, it just crash and says it can not find symbol

`Dyld Error Message:
   Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
   Referenced from: path/to/my/app
   Excepted in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Version/C/Foundation`

i know that on os x 10.8 , the symbol NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown doesn exist at all , but i did run into any code section that will use this symbol. so how can i avoid this ? just do not let it at startup, and everything will be ok.(i think)

or , is there any runtime trick/check i can use?

thank you!

**UPDATE**

i solved this problem by using **weak link** or put  **@class NSURLSession** in a pch file.

the problem is in my .m file

`@import <3rd-part-lib1.h>
@import <3rd-part=lib2.h>
- (void)someMethod:()
{
    if (above 10.8) {
        do staffs with a 3-rd part library's object whose superClass is NSURLSession
    } else {
        do staffs with a 3-rd part library's object whose superClass is NSURLSession
    }
}`

I have done those runtime checks. and just use @class to tell the link that don't look for NSURLSession class. it'will be there when i need it. but in 10.8 , i have have NSURLSession and i won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with weak linking. When a framework is weak linked, all of its symbols can be compiled and linked (including exported C variables and functions), even when they are not actually present.

Replace `-framework Foundation` with `-weak_framework Foundation` in linker options (or set 'weak' flag in Xcode UI).

Availability of Objective-C classes can be tested with `if ([NSNewClass class])`.

Availability of exported C symbols must be tested with `if (&NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown != NULL)`.

Note that you must write `!= NULL`, you can't use just `if (&NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown)` for some reason (optimizer?).

Comment: it's not what i mean. see my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

To determine which OS X version is running on, you can use NSAppKitVersionNumber.
Like that

```
if (NSAppKitVersionNumber > NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8)
{
    execute code related to OS X 10.9 and higher
}
```